# Finding eigenvalues from characteristic polynomial

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I am finding it extremely hard to find the eigenvalues after finding the characteristic polynomial.

For example (instead of $\lambda$ I will use $x$) I have:

$-x^3+x^2+16x+20=0$, how do i find the eigenvalues? From the book, it says to use the factors of the constant, in this case the constant is $20$; and the one factors that does equals to $0$ are $5$ and $-2$. So how do I go about finding it?

I tried to take $x-5$ factor of $-x^3+x^2+16x+20$, but I cant seem to do it right.

Comment: It's a pity that none of the answers seem to provide a fast and an easy way to take out the factors without losing much time. The question should be "is there any easy way to..?", to be sure to get good answers, otherwise everybody sticks to your example and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x^3-x^2-16x-20=(x-5)(x^2+4x+4)=(x-5)(x+2)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that if $f(a)=0$ then there is a $q(x)$ that $f(x)=(x-a)q(x)$. in your question $-5^3+5^2+16.5+20=0$.